# File download fails on slow network

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, download

I have classic Asp.Net(c#) application for file download. I have tested the file download functionality upto 2GB. Everything works fine on Intranet and on high speed internet connection.

But when tested on **slow network (low bandwidth) this functionality fails** with "Network Failure" error. It is seen that files as small as 1MB also gets fail. Sometimes it is observed that upto 90% of file content(small file) gets downloaded and then I get an error. I am currently simulating this using Google chrome Network bandwidth throttling feature (F12 -->Network -->Online Dropdown -->Slow 3G).

I need help on following

1. Any code changes(api/method...) suggestion
2. Any IIS settings we have missed
3. Any web.config/Machine.config setting we have missed

We tried executionTimeOut, WebLimits settings in IIS & Application host configurations.

### Current code is similar to following

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
Response.AppendHeader("ETag", "\"" + _EncodedData + "\"");
Response.AppendHeader("Last-Modified", lastUpdateTiemStamp);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName.Name);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (FileName.Length - startBytes).ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

_BinaryReader.BaseStream.Seek(startBytes, SeekOrigin.Begin);

//Dividing the data in 1024 bytes package
int maxCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((FileName.Length - startBytes + 0.0) / 1024);

//Download in block of 1024 bytes
int i;
for (i = 0; i < maxCount && Response.IsClientConnected; i++)
{
    Response.BinaryWrite(_BinaryReader.ReadBytes(1024));
    Response.Flush();
}
```

Appreciate any help in solving this **low bandwidth, file download issue.**

Comment: I think problem is here in for statement Response.IsClientConnected. for any of the instance when connection to the client is broken this for loop will exit and hence download fails. You can handle it by waiting and retrying to send that packet again and again multiple times when client is not connected.

Comment: @VIVEK Response.IsClientConnected is used to save Server's resources when the client disconnects in between of a long running process. When it turns False the server can stop the process of sending data. I believe unless you are using web sockets you can not initiate a connection from server to the client once they are disconnected.